# Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' to 'System.Exception'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
try
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        context.Contracts.Add(_contract);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
{                
    foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                validationError.ErrorMessage);                       
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```

> //Error: "Cannot implicitly convert
>   type'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' 
>            to 'System.Exception'"//  Getting this error while using System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException in Catch
>   block

Comment: I have test the code you've posted but it's come with no problem actually. It nicely projects the expected exception and no casting exception throws. Are you sure there is no other code lines which might effect the behavior of the code just posted?

Comment: Hi Ali, yes there is few lines of code before try block. But that 1 working fine. I am only getting this exception while using catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex).

Comment: You should post the entire stack trace.